# Set focus on mail message when composing mail on iPad

Tags: ipad

in an application I am building I implemented a function to let users send email back as feedback. The default mail compose screen shows up on my iPad, but I would like to replicate native Mail.app feature, so that the keyboard will show up and it will be focused on the message when the modal mail view appears.

This will enable users to start writing their feedback without clicking on to the message to show the keyboard, which is the case now.

Thanx for help
Ladislav

Comment: Anyone has a solution for me?

Comment: How to set focus on message and show the keyboard...

Answer (score 0):

programatically set first responder on the first field you want yo be focused something like
[txtfieldname setFirstResponder];